# Get/Set cookies from qml

Tags: cookies, xmlhttprequest, qml

I am writting a client program. When I login, the server will send some cookies to me in the 'Set-Cookie' header field. 
I need to get the cookies, because the rest of the request will need them.

I try to get the cookies with xmlhttprequest.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"), but failed.
I don't want to use C++, so could it be possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible without using C++.

Look at source [code](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/declarative/qml/qdeclarativexmlhttprequest.cpp#line1102) for `QDeclarativeXMLHttpRequest::fillHeadersList()` method. It particularly removes set-cookie and set-cookie2 headers, following w3c [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-getallresponseheaders) for `XMLHttpRequest` object. Specifically behaviour of `getAllResponseHeaders` method. That is:

> Return all the HTTP headers, excluding headers that are a case-insensitive match for Set-Cookie or Set-Cookie2, ...

Comment: Can cookies be handled by an app using only QML/JS? With no HTML or webview of any kind? Essentially QML acting like a browser?